# How to solve this equation using sympy library?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I'm trying to solve this equation, essentially find the time when X = 16.9164. gravity_FORCE[0],drag_FORCE[0], and magnus_FORCE[0] are all slices from an array added together so they make a scalar quantity. h_release is also a scalar. When I type this into python I don't get an error, but rather get an empty array

```
[]
```

when I solve for the time 't'. Can someone help me understand why?

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
X = (1/2)*((gravity_FORCE[0]+drag_FORCE[0]+ \
magnus_FORCE[0]).145)*t**2 - h_release
t = Symbol('t')
balltime = solve(X-16.9164, t)
print(balltime)
```

If it helps gravity_force = 0, drag_force = -.01,magnus_force = .8, h_release = .3. THANKS!!

Comment: it looks like you are defining `t` to be a sympy symbol only after you use it.

Comment: what does this mean @ptb ? I tried defining it before I used it and for this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You use `t` on line 4 and define it on line 5.  I suspect the `.145` is also 
an error.  please post a runnable example.